# 'Detected call to method without [Pure]'...but Pure is there

Tags: c#, code-contracts

This is part of a contract class for an interface.

```
[Pure]
public bool IsDirty() {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public void Save() {
    Contract.Ensures(!this.IsDirty()); //WARNING
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

It's producing this warning:

> warning CC1036: CodeContracts: Detected call to method 'IEntityObject.IsDirty' without [Pure] in contracts of method 'EntityObjectContract.Save'.

...even though the `Pure` attribute is present. I've tried rebuilding, re-opening Visual Studio, but every time the same results. Any idea how to get rid of this warning? Am I missing something?

Comment: You must set `Pure` attribute to method `Save` also.

Comment: That didn't do it. I'm not sure it would make sense anyway for every method that uses a `Pure` method in its contract to also be `Pure`.

Comment: Looks like it's looking for the attribute in the `IEntityObject.IsDirty` property. It would seem to me that you need to add this attribute to the method declaration in the **interface**?

Comment: @HighCore: That did it. How strange that pre/post-conditions have to be specified on the contract class but `Pure` has to be on the interface itself. Thanks for your help. Feel free to post an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like it's looking for the attribute in the `IEntityObject.IsDirty()` method.

It would seem to me that you need to add this attribute to the method declaration in the **interface**?

```
public interface IEntityObject
{
    [Pure]
    bool IsDirty();

    //...
}
```